# Change border color of empty inputs inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have the below code which turns the borders red of the inputs when it's missing a value; Problem is it changes ALL the input borders red even if only one input is missing.

```js
$('#button_one').click(function(){
  var result = $(".className input[required]").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
  }).length == 0;

  if (result) {
    // Loads the next section of the form...
  } else {
    $("className input[required]").css('border', 'solid 1px red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='className'>
  <label>Full Name <input type="text" required/></label>
  <label>Date of Birth <input type="date" required/></label>
</div>
```

I know there are other ways to do it. However those HTML sections are added dynamically with another button. So I can never really know how many DIV input sections there are.

Comment: `$("className input[required]:empty")` should do the trick. However, you should really give HTML5 a chance.

Comment: Awesome! can you elaborate on HTML5? Anything I can read in regards to my question?

Comment: Instead of relying on a script to do your validation, you could rely on the native validation mechanisms available in all modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation. It literally works cross browser and many devices have specific UI methods adjusted for them (like scrolling to the element, focusing it, etc...). It's also integrated with CSS module (you can use `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors.)

Comment: Probably the nicest thing about native validity is that it bubbles. So you can group inputs into fieldsets and select the valid/invalid using the above selectors on fieldset (and on form, of course).